# Directive not able to access ng-repeated children until after a digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm writing a directive placed on ul elements, often with li children that are stamped out using ng-repeat. I need access to these children to make some copies, but in my postLink function, if I call iElement.children(), I'll get an empty list! Even stranger is that if I access the DOM property, i.e. iElement[0].children, I get the actual list. I can fix this by wrapping everything in a $timeout, but it creates a flicker as I do some DOM manipulation in my code. I tried using scope.$evalAsync, but then the children aren't there, as before. Any idea as to what's going on? I'm most curious as to why the DOM children property works but the jqLite .children() method doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What probably happens here is that the directive bound and fires **before** the ng-repeat finished rendering the elements on the view.

You can solve this with an $broadcast event from your controller and catch it inside of the directive with an $on event listener.

```
if ($scope.$last === true) {
   $scope.$broadcast('ngRepeatFinished');
 }
```

and the inside your directive

```
scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(){...});
```

You can also create a directive for the ng-repeat event

```
.directive('ngRepeatFinished', function () {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, element, attr) {
         if (scope.$last === true) {
                scope.$broadcast('ngRepeatFinished');
        } 
    }
 }
});
```

Use $broadcast or $emit depending on your code hierarchy.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the response. I assume that all of this event broadcasting and processing will happen before the first browser rendering, and so should work perfectly.